# Giveaway command time converting error Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is the code I have, the time is not being converted, and I don't know what to do anymore. If you know what to do, let me know how to do this

Here is what I got so far:

```
def convert(time):
  pos = ["s","m","h","d"]

  time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d": 3600*24}

  unit = time[-1]

  if unit not in pos:
    return -1
  try:
    val = int(time[:-1])
  except:
    return -2

  return val * time_dict[unit]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages  = True)
async def giveaway(ctx, time : str, *, prize: str):

    embed = discord.Embed(title=prize,
                          description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with :tada: to enter!\nTime Remaining: **{time}** seconds",
                          color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color, )

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)

    user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user] # Check the reactions/don't count the bot reaction

    if len(user_list) == 0:
        await ctx.send("No one reacted.") 
    else:
        winner = random.choice(user_list)
        await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention} You have won the {prize}!")
```

When I type in 2m meaning 2 minutes, it shows 2m seconds remaining, now I know why it says seconds because I have not updated the response yet, but the time is only 2 seconds plus the 3 seconds delay time. Basically a total of around 6 seconds.

I did just throw 2 commands from stack overflow together, and it is like putting in a Lamborghini head gasket and a dodge engine block, I know it should not work, even with the little bit of modifications, I kinda do see whats wrong now, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure why, but you only did `await asyncio.sleep(3)`. Shouldn't you add a `await asyncio.sleep(int(convert(time)))` after the `await asyncio.sleep(3)`?

Comment: I just edited it because I just realized the time converter is different to the code itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I revised your code and changed the `giveaway` command a little bit. After a few modifications, the command worked as it should for me. Here is how I re-defined it:

```
def convert(time):
    pos = ["s", "m", "h", "d"]

    time_dict = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 3600 * 24}

    unit = time[-1]

    if unit not in pos:
        return -1
    try:
        val = int(time[:-1])
    except:
        return -2

    return val * time_dict[unit]


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def giveaway(ctx, time: str, *, prize: str):
    time = convert(time)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=prize,
                          description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with :tada: to enter!\nTime Remaining: **{time}** seconds",
                          color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color)

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await asyncio.sleep(int(time))

    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)

    user_list = [user for user in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if
                 user != client.user]  # Check the reactions/don't count the bot reaction

    if len(user_list) == 0:
        await ctx.send("No one reacted.")
    else:
        winner = random.choice(user_list)
        await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention} You have won the {prize}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for converting time.

```
import re
from discord.ext.commands import BadArgument

time_regex = re.compile(r"(?:(\d{1,5})(h|s|m|d))+?")
time_dict = {"h": 3600, "s": 1, "m": 60, "d": 86400}


def convert(argument):
  args = argument.lower()
  matches = re.findall(time_regex, args)
  time = 0
  for key, value in matches:
    try:
      time += time_dict[value] * float(key)
    except:
      raise BadArgument
  return round(time)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did that and it don't know what regex is, thank you for the help

Comment: re.findall is just like str.index but more complex and usefull.